# How to know svn repository URL using which I can take checkout?

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I am new to svn , I have installed it in ubuntu . I have created svn repository as mentioned in   [1]: https://civicactions.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-svn-repository-in-7-simple-steps/ . I created it successfully , but now how other developer can take checkout of this repository as I am unable to know URL for this repository . Should I use SVN: protocol , or else ?? if yes then how ?? Please help me .

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/310300/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-svn-repo

Comment: svn info giving me error like svn: E155007: '/home/SVN_REPO' is not a working copy where I have created repository.